# Unwanted padding in android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, padding

I have an imageview and textview in a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation. Do not know why the textview has a space on the left that I can not remove ...
I tested with padding, gravities, etc. ...

This is my xml and result in an image

Any idea?

Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dot" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_resultado"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/negroLetras"
            android:textSize="@dimen/titles" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="%"
        android:textColor="@color/negroLetras"
        android:textSize="@dimen/titles" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propably you have something wrong with you drawable "dot" or other values like dimen etc.
I think that because I used your code without this values with other sample values and layout was ok.

Comment: Yeah I also think that might be the problem, it worked alright when I used different drawable and deleted your text dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code. Your code is perfect. May your problem be in image. Check it or replace it with other and then check it.

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest you to change a little bit your layout?

Delete second LinearLayout and use a TextView like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_resultado"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dot"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/negroLetras"
    android:textSize="@dimen/titles" />
```